# How do you find y where y is a function of u, u is a function of v, and v is a function of x using the chain rule?

Tags: calculus

Develop a 3-step chain rule for the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$, where y is a function of u, u is a function of v, and v is a function of x. 
Hence find $y=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Answer: $\frac{x}{(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

I know that you could solve it using the quotient rule and the chain rule but I'm not sure how it's supposed to be solved using $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}$ (the textbook wants me to solve it using that).

Any ideas?

Comment: $y={1 \over u}$, $u=1+\sqrt v$, $v=1-x^2$ is a possible decomposition.

Comment: Just to add to the above comment, you want to be writing $y$ as the composition of 3 functions.